# How to use Ansible command with items?

Tags: ansible

I want to configure my Ansible playbook to copy certain lines out of my `/etc/hosts` file into a temporary file. This should be easy to do:

```
---
hosts: 127.0.0.1
gather_facts: False
tasks:
  - command: grep {{ item }} /etc/hosts >> /tmp/hosts_to_backup
    with_items:
      - web
      - database
```

I'd think this would work but I'm getting an error:

> TypeError: string indicies must be integers, not str

I know Ansible is picky about unquoted braces so I put double quotes around the entire command line but I still get the error.

```
- command: "grep {{ item }} /etc/hosts >> /tmp/hosts_to_backup"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<sup>I have no idea why you get the error you claim you get (maybe it's an OS-related thing if your system returns a strange error message to Ansible).</sup>

One thing for sure is you cannot use file redirection with `command` module. Instead you need to use `shell` module, so replace your action with:

```
- shell: grep {{ item }} /etc/hosts >> /tmp/hosts_to_backup
```

Other than that, there is no problem with `with_items` in your task. There is no `-` for the play though.

The following code works:

```
---
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
    - shell: grep {{ item }} /etc/hosts >> /tmp/hosts_to_backup
      with_items:
        - web
        - database
```

Comment: You are correct.  I needed to use shell instead of command.  Thanks.